# Motion using LayoutParams and Paddings Android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I've an implementation of a translucent to opaque `ActionBar` effect (Google Play's App Pages, Google Music) in an app I'm developing, I've made a `ScrollView` that notifies when the scrolling changes, my listener then calculates a ratio of opacity for the `ActionBar` relative to some max height. This is working great, but now I've implemented something like this in my scroll change listener.

```
float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), limitHeight) / limitHeight;
                        toolBarDrawableAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
                        toolBarTypeColorDrawable.setAlpha(toolBarDrawableAlpha);
int dexEntryPictureNewSize = Math
                                .max(dexEntryPictureMinSize, (int) ((1 - ratio / 2) * dexEntryPictureSize));
                        dexEntryPicture.getLayoutParams().height = dexEntryPictureNewSize;
                        dexEntryPicture.getLayoutParams().width = dexEntryPictureNewSize;
                        dexEntryPicture.requestLayout();

int dexEntryPictureNewBottomMargin = Math.max(dexEntryPictureMarginBottom,
                                    Math.min(dexEntryPictureMaxMarginBottom,
                                            (int) ((ratio * 1.5) * dexEntryPictureMaxMarginBottom)));
                            ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) dexEntryPicture
                                    .getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = dexEntryPictureNewBottomMargin;
                        dexEntryPicture.requestLayout();

int dexEntryNameNewTopPadding = Math.max(dexEntryNamePaddingTop,
                                Math.min(dexEntryNameMaxPaddingTop, (int) ((ratio) * dexEntryNameMaxPaddingTop)));
                        dexEntryName.setPadding(dexEntryName.getPaddingLeft(), dexEntryNameNewTopPadding,
                                dexEntryName.getPaddingRight(), dexEntryName.getPaddingBottom());
```

As you can see, I use the same ratio calculated for the opacity to change some height, width, margin, padding values in my views, this is working great too, but I've been wondering if there's a way to accomplish this in a more efficient way or if I'm making some horrible performance mistakes, I only have one device to test this and it's running fairly snappy, really smooth but would like to know if lesser devices won't whine about it.

If you are wondering what's the final effect that I'm going for, it's some sort of parallax (?) scrolling where a fixed background view has another centered view in it (like a profile image circle) and this centered view shrink and expands relative to the opacity ratio, also some paddings are moved so the view seems to be pushed to top.

Comment: You can use methods like `setTranslationX`, `setTranslationY`, `setScaleX`, `setScaleY` on the view.

Comment: Those methods change the way the view is drawn, but to my knowledge they do not change the layout of the view, and so will not force a relayout of the view hierarchy.

Comment: I will try, I'll get back to you, shouldn't your message be an answer?